# (Groovy | 12.04 | armv7l) bash: rosrun: command not found

Tags: ros-groovy, ubuntu-precise, rosrun, ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I ran the following commands:

```
$ roscore
$ rosrun turtlesim turtlesim_node
```

and obtained the following error:

```
bash: rosrun: command not found
```

My environment reads:

```
root@localhost:~# export | grep ROS
declare -x ROS_DISTRO="groovy"
declare -x ROS_ETC_DIR="/opt/ros/groovy/etc/ros"
declare -x ROS_MASTER_URI="http://localhost:11311"
declare -x ROS_PACKAGE_PATH="/home/ubuntu/ros_ws:/opt/ros/groovy/share:/opt/ros/groovy/stacks"
declare -x ROS_ROOT="/opt/ros/groovy/share/ros"
```

And was not able to find the rosrun file at `/opt/ros/groovy/bin`

Any suggestions?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/56818/(groovy-%7C-12.04-%7C-armv7l)-bash:-rosrun:-command-not-found/) by [amrivera](https://answers.ros.org/users/3700/amrivera/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2013-03-02

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2013-03-02**:
How did you install ROS? If you installed from debs, which debs did you install?

**Comment by [amrivera](https://answers.ros.org/users/3700/amrivera/) on 2013-03-11**:
I used this link --> http://packages.ros.org/web/rosinstall/generate/raw/groovy/desktop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The env variable you need for this is PATH:

```
$ env | grep ^PATH=
PATH=/opt/ros/groovy/bin:...
```

This entry is added by sourcing /opt/ros/groovy/setup.*sh

---

Originally posted by [KruseT](https://answers.ros.org/users/888/kruset/) with karma: 7848 on 2013-03-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [amrivera](https://answers.ros.org/users/3700/amrivera/) on 2013-03-14**:
It does have the PATH info that you mention.